# Similar words Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've a word, `$my_word="MYWORD";` Now, I want to make a regular expression of that, which detects the following cases

```
--> MY WORD
--> MYWORDS
--> MYWORDSISMINE
--> WORD
--> WORDS
```

Now, I want to make a regular expression in php using `preg_match()` which detects the following occurrences.

My Try:

```
$mycase = str_replace(' ', '|', $my_word); // where $str would be MYWORD
$mycase = (preg_match("/\b(".$mycase.")\b/", $someFuzzyWord)); // $someFuzzyWord is the user entered string which needs to be filter
```

I had putted the `|` so that it can detect every word and also tried `.*` after starting and trailing of a word so that it can be detect a substring.

Comment: There isn't a space in my_word, then why you replace space with pipe?

Comment: Can `(MY)? ?WORDS?(ISMINE)?` help you?

Comment: If I understand well you need solution not only for this case but with any word you will use in future. If that is true, then regexp alone won't able to handle it.

Comment: Yeah, @zolo any word matching with this cases. But ive words in my loop and can populate them to make a regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj that's is the case If there is a space.

Comment: How would you expect that regular expression knows which characters of your word could be eliminating and which should be there? I mean with regular expression you won't able to specify that if MY is not there, only the WORD that is fine, however the "or" is already not an acceptable solution, however it is still part of the string "word". If we forget that idea that regexp trying to figure out which part may be omitted, then it can be solved.

Comment: If you have a single string of space delimited search words, what makes you think word boundaries will work in the regex? The other problem is the string metachars should be escaped if you will use them as a regex literal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you:

```
$mycase = str_replace("MY", "", $my_word);
$regex = "(MY)? ?" + $mycase + "S?(ISMINE)?";
$mycase = (preg_match("/\b(".$mycase.")\b/i", $someFuzzyWord));
```